# Dynamic alteration of graphic/canvas/divs

Tags: php, css, svg, graphics, imagemagick

I need to be able to have some kind of a canvas in which I can draw A and manipulate it dynamically towards B. (For A and B see example drawing)

- The size of all rectacles must be adaptable
- the skewing of the red rectangle
- and the rotation of the whole set

I am unsure which is the right way to go. I tried simple HTML with CSS3 transformations and dont really get anywhere without extensive JS calculation since I would have to fake transform the red rectangles in 3D to get the expected impression - which then requires a "faked" positioning for A and B to connected they way they are supposed to.

Any other ideas? Draw it with imagemagick and PHP? SVG manipulation? I am relatively open towards the approach.

Would appreciate some input.

Example drawing: http://www.steffen-behn.de/m3/reifen.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that transforms can give you everything that is needed

```css
div {
    transition: all 1s;
}
.base {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  left: 50px;
  top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
   perspective: 100px;
}

.side {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  position: absolute;
  }

#side1 {
  bottom: 100%;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#side2 {
  top: 100%;
  transform-origin: top center;
}

.base:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2) rotate(20deg);
  }

.base:hover #side1 {
  transform: scaleY(1.1) rotateX(-20deg);
;
}
.base:hover #side2 {
  transform: scaleY(1.1) rotateX(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="base">
  <div class="side" id="side1"></div>
  <div class="side" id="side2"></div>
</div>
```

Hover to see the transform

EDIT

Another idea. Not sure if it will suit you, but let's give it a try. Can not make the red zones border - only, only solid color.

```css
// customize here
.base {
    width: 80px;
    height: 200px;
}
.side {
    height: 42px;
}
.side:after, .side:before {
    width: 10px;
}
// end of customization part


div {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
.base {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 200px;
    border: solid black 1px;
}



.side {
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px red;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1px;
    background-color: red;
}

#side1 {
    top: 100%;
}

#side2 {
    bottom: 100%;
}

.side:after, .side:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}

.side:before {
    right: 100%;
}
.side:after {
    left: 100%;
}

#side1:before {
    background: linear-gradient(to top left, red 50%, transparent 50%);
    border-bottom: solid red 1px;
}

#side1:after {
    background: linear-gradient(to top right, red 50%, transparent 50%);
    border-bottom: solid red 1px;
}

#side2:before {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, red 50%, transparent 50%);
    border-top: solid red 1px;
    top: -1px;
}

#side2:after {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, red 50%, transparent 50%);
    border-top: solid red 1px;
    top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="base">
<div class="side" id="side1"></div>
<div class="side" id="side2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! My problem with this solution is, I cant simply parameterize it. I cant set the width, height of the rectangles and the skewing without somehow calculating new positions and "rotation". I would like to be able to set the upper width and lower width of the red rectangles with a resulting skew or be able to calculate it.

Comment: Can you provide an e xample of the parametrization that you want ? What are the values that you have to begin with, and the end result ?

Comment: Basically I want o be able to set the exact upper width of the red rectangles, the lower width should exactly equal the black rectangle. This is suppose to become a graphical representation for a tyre calculator. Basically the black rectangle represents the rim and the red ones the tyre around it. I already managed to get quite far with a manually written SVG which can be altered by PHP/CSS. So far this seems to be the easiest way to go.

Comment: I have now a working prototype with some simple lines of spaghetti PHP ;)
http://steffen-behn.de/RaederRechner/rad.php?tyreWidth=265&tyreSidewall=35&rimDiameter=18&rimWidth=10&rimOffset=40&spacerWidth=20&wheelCamber=-2

Comment: Really really cool idea. The borders arent even necessary. If you take them out and get rid of all the "-1px" its actually very straight foward!

Only problem for me, I also need to be able to have the "skewing" to negative values. Since I didnt describe that properly, I will accept your answer - I really like the approach.

Example for negative values: http://steffen-behn.de/RaederRechner/rad.php?tyreWidth=235&tyreSidewall=35&rimDiameter=18&rimWidth=10&rimOffset=40&spacerWidth=20&wheelCamber=0